# Is it possible to run a code at certain time period?

Tags: java

So, I am writing a Java code where I want the program to take content from the web every monday 12 am.

I found **SO** many answers telling me how to run a program for certain amount of time. I want to run the program and execute every monday morning.

I want to know if any one has ANY idea where to start?

I found of AlarmManager for android applications (which is sort what I want) but I want it for Java program not application.

Or is this even possible?

Comment: Can't you run it in a cron-job?

Comment: why don't you use a loop? Use `Thread.sleep()` so that it sleeps most of the time and does not deplete CPU cycles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**[Scheduled Tasks With Cron for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron?hl=es)**

Answer (score 1):

Sure!  If you are on linux or mac, just set up a cronjob to run at `0 0 * * 1`

It'd be something like:

`java MyScript.java`

as the task.

Comment: I'm a little rusty on cron, but you just need to research "every MONDAY" for cron.

Comment: I have windows, can I still do that? I have to research what a cronjob is though

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/31506  alternatively, instead of doing a cronjob then, just use the windows task scheduler to execute. it's extremely easy to set up on windows. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know it is possible!

Comment: you do need administrative privs, so if you don't, then you'll have to find an alternative

Comment: Aww, thanks! Sadly I don't, I'll use Corn whenever I need something to code at home. I need it for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

http://quartz-scheduler.org/ is the standard tool to setup cron-like jobs

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is using Windows Task Manager!